# TinyMce 5 setcontent unable to set html properly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

I am writing a tinymce custom plugin called Mergetable. which will merger two user selected table.

Problem statement:

1. TinyMce is not allowing to select two table , by using shift and mouse I can select content of the table. So I can't use tinmce.activeeditor.selection.getNode() method instead using tinmce.activeeditor.selection.getContent().

   2. Form getcontent() method I am getting proper html of both table. After do some operation while setting content using tinmce.activeeditor.selection.setContent() both table merged properly but two more table with empty td created one in top and one in bottom . Please see below plugin code.

**code**:

```
(function () {
    var mergeTable = (function () {
    'use strict';
    tinymce.PluginManager.add("mergeTable", function (editor, url) {
        function Merge(){

            var selectedhtml=editor.selection.getContent();
        //using getContent() as getnode returning body node
            var dv=document.createElement('div'); 
            dv.innerHTML= selectedhtml;   
            var tableElements = dv.getElementsByTagName('TABLE');

            if (tableElements.length == 2) {

                var tableOne = tableElements[0];
                var tableTwo = tableElements[1];
                var tempTable = null;
                var offsetLeft = tableOne.offsetLeft;
                var offsetTop = tableOne.offsetTop;
                var elem = tableElements[0];


                if (tableOne.nodeName == "TABLE" && tableTwo.nodeName == "TABLE") {
                    for (var r = 0; r < tableTwo.rows.length; r++) {
                        var newTR = tableOne.insertRow(tableOne.rows.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < tableTwo.rows[r].cells.length; i++) {
                            var newTD = newTR.insertCell()
                            newTD.innerHTML = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].innerHTML;
                            newTD.colSpan = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].colSpan;
                            newTD.rowSpan = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].rowSpan;
                            newTD.style.cssText = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].style.cssText;
                            if (tableOne.style.border != "") {
                                newTD.style.border = "1px dotted #BFBFBF"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    tableTwo.remove();
                    console.log(dv.innerHTML);

                    editor.selection.setContent(dv.innerHTML);
                    editor.nodeChanged();
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please select two tables");
                }

            }




        }

        editor.ui.registry.addButton('mergeTable', {
            text: "Merge Table",
            onAction: function(){ Merge();}
          });

    });

    }());
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix my problem by using some work around . Instead use setContent() method. I have remove selected content and use insertContent().
Please find working code below.

```
(function () {
    var mergeTable = (function () {
    'use strict';
    tinymce.PluginManager.add("mergeTable", function (editor, url) {
        var cmd = function (command) {
            return function () {
              return editor.execCommand(command);
            };
          };
        function Merge(){

            var selectedhtml=editor.selection.getContent();
            var dv=document.createElement('div'); 
            dv.innerHTML= selectedhtml;   
            var tableElements = dv.getElementsByTagName('TABLE');

            if (tableElements.length == 2) {

                var tableOne = tableElements[0];
                var tableTwo = tableElements[1];
                var tempTable = null;                
                var tableOneMaxCell=0
                var tabletwoMaxCell=0
                var tempCellcount=0
                 var tableOneRowcount=tableOne.rows.length;
                tableOne.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(function(e){
                    tempCellcount= e.querySelectorAll("td").length ;
                    if(tempCellcount>tableOneMaxCell)
                    {
                        tableOneMaxCell=tempCellcount;
                    }
                   });
                   tableTwo.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(function(e){
                    tempCellcount= e.querySelectorAll("td").length ;
                    if(tempCellcount>tabletwoMaxCell)
                    {
                        tabletwoMaxCell=tempCellcount;
                    }
                   });


                if (tableOne.nodeName == "TABLE" && tableTwo.nodeName == "TABLE") {
                    for (var r = 0; r < tableTwo.rows.length; r++) {
                        var newTR = tableOne.insertRow(tableOne.rows.length);
                        for (var i = 0; i < tableTwo.rows[r].cells.length; i++) {
                            var newTD = newTR.insertCell()
                            newTD.innerHTML = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].innerHTML;
                            newTD.colSpan = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].colSpan;
                            newTD.rowSpan = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].rowSpan;
                            newTD.style.cssText = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].style.cssText;
                            if (tableOne.style.border != "") {
                                newTD.style.border = "1px dotted #BFBFBF"
                            }
                            if(i==tableTwo.rows[r].cells.length-1 && tableOneMaxCell>tabletwoMaxCell){
                                newTD.colSpan = tableTwo.rows[r].cells[i].colSpan + (tableOneMaxCell-tabletwoMaxCell);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for( var t1=0; t1<tableOneRowcount; t1++ ){
                        var celllen=tableOne.rows[t1].cells.length;
                        tableOne.rows[t1].cells[celllen-1].colSpan=tableOne.rows[t1].cells[celllen-1].colSpan+(tabletwoMaxCell-tableOneMaxCell)

                    }
                    tableTwo.remove();

                    // cmd('mceTableDelete');

                    // var selObj = editor.selection;                     
                    // var selstartRange = selObj.getStart();
                    // var selectendRange= selObj.getEnd();
                    // var selrng=selObj.getRng();
                    // console.log(selstartRange);
                    // console.log(selectendRange);
                    // editor.execCommand('mceTableDelete');
                    // selObj.removeAllRanges();
                    editor.selection.getSelectedBlocks().forEach(function(elm){     
                        elm.remove();
                    });  


                        // selObj.setRng(selrng,true);
                        editor.insertContent(dv.innerHTML);
                        editor.nodeChanged();

                }
                else {
                    editor.notificationManager.open({
                        text: 'Please select two table.',
                        type: 'error'
                     });
                }
            }
            else {
                editor.notificationManager.open({
                    text: 'Please select two table.',
                    type: 'error'
                 });
            }

        }

        editor.ui.registry.addButton('mergeTable', {
            text: "MergeTable",
            onAction: function(){ Merge();}
          });

    });

    }());
}());
```